# Instal plugin from disk, android studio

Tags: macos, android-studio

I am working on mac book pro, OS X EL Captain 10.11 and I faced strange problem, when in Android Studio 4 I open "Android Studio -> preferences -> plugins -> Instal plugin from disk" it stop response on any actions. And I don't know whats the problem, on other mac mini it works fine (OS X Yosemite, Android studio 1.2.2). My only guess that problems with access, bcs after I click "instal plugin from disk" should open file chooser window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it is some sort of bug, mb it will help some1, but after I play with size of preference window in Android studio the file chooser dialog appears